# How to install pip, if I get a warning every time?

Tags: python, pip

I want to install pip (to python 3.8). But every time I try to do it I get a warning that says:

> The scrips installed in a directory, which is not PATH

I added the path in the environment variables, but it still is not working. I tried to install from cmd and from pycharm terminal, but it didn't work.

Comment: pip comes by default with python, use `python -m pip` as pip

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding `pip` or `python` to path, make sure you are adding the `bin` **directory**, emphasizing **directory** to the PATH. If you add the individual .exe files, it won't work(at least it did not in my case).

Also, if you have `python` in the PATH and it works, (as others have pointed out) you can use:

```bash
python -m pip
```